# How to handle "no such file or directory" in os.Stat

Tags: go, unix, stat

I have a piece of code that is looking to `stat` a file and return some default values if the file does not exist. Namely, the piece of code looks something like the following:

```golang
fileInfo, err := os.Stat(absolutePath)
if err != nil {
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return <default val>, nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf(...)
}
```

To "catch" the "file does not exist" error I have read that it's advised to use `os.IsNotExist` to check if the error indicates the file does not exist. However, `os.IsNotExist` does not catch this error since the platform returns `open <blah>: no such file or directory`. I can add my own error handling here but is there is an idiomatic way to handle "file does not exist" errors from `os` calls? It seems like the error handled by the `os.IsNotExist` check is special cased to just one type of potential "file does not exist" error.

Comment: Did you confirm that os.IsNotExist returns false for that error?  The function returns true on the playground. https://go.dev/play/p/o43mqpqpo_q

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/os#IsNotExist), you'll see this:

> **`func IsNotExist`**
>
> ```golang
> func IsNotExist(err error) bool
> ```
>
> `IsNotExist` returns a boolean indicating whether the error is known to
> report that a file or directory does not exist. It is satisfied by
> `ErrNotExist` as well as some `syscall` errors.
>
> This function predates errors.Is. It only supports errors returned by the os package.
> **New code should use `errors.Is(err, fs.ErrNotExist)`**. [*emph. mine*]

Comment: ahhhh that did it! `errors.Is(err, fs.ErrNotExist)` works just fine for me. Reading comprehension is hard :P Thanks!